# Payment with the MSR (Magnetic Stripe Reader)

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, point-of-sale

I am new in POS(Point of Sale). I have an Motorola Enterprise device with MSR reader hardware. I want to integrate the payment module. When i scan any payment card MSR will fetch the data from card and displayed in the mobile device.

I need to process the credit or debit card for payment. I have few questions regarding this

1. What is flow chart of POS for payment?
2. How to do authorization of card and card holder?
3. How to do payment?
4. How to send data to acquire?
5. Is it necessary to integrate Payment gateway to do payment?

Comment: Sounds interesting from a tinkering perspective, though wouldn't it be much easier to get the related hardware/app (both are free) from the providers you mention?

Comment: You could just use [USBSwiper](http://www.usbswiper.com) instead.  It already works with PayPal.  ;)  But yes, you would just receive the data off the card in your app, parse it accordingly, and use it to generate a payment request with PayPal's API.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have already a device who scan and read the data from the card. I showed in the mobile device. My question is what to do next? We need to use any payment gateway for payment processing or we can do it with any other way

Comment: Any suggestion please

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

*1. Is it necessary to integrate Payment gateway to do payment?*

- YES, if the device you use is not integrated already.

*2. What is flow chart of POS for payment?*
*3. How to do authorization of card and card holder?*
*4. How to do payment?*
*5. How to send data to acquire?*

- It's upto the payment gateway you prefer.

From your question, I assume that your device SDK just displays the card details when you swipe it. If then, just check with your preferred payment gateway if they support Seamless Integration or Custom UI payment. Some gateways have their own Seamless / Custom UI payment SDK's, so the values you receive from the MSR reader such as card number, expiry, etc can be passed through params to complete the payment process. You may ask your payment gateway customer support about it. Personally, I have integrated Razorpay in one of my projects. Here's their documentation https://docs.razorpay.com/page/android-custom-ui-sdk-v2x but the device API should be 19 and above.

**PS: PayUMoney and PayUBiz** can also support seamless integration. https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/6.-Android-SDK-Integration#22-seamless-using-your-own-ui